# add link background for one link only html

Tags: html, css

so I want to change the background of my links individually like this but with out it changing every website links to do the same.

```
      a:link {
        color: white;
        background-color: transparent;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      a:visited {
        color: grey;
        background-color: transparent;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      a:hover {
        color: lightgrey;
        background-color: transparent;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }

      a:active {
        color: black;
        background-color: transparent;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
```

Is there a way to put it into the code like this
`<a style="**code inserted here**" href="**link**" >`
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```css
a.fancylink:link {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.fancylink:visited {
  color: grey;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.fancylink:hover {
  color: lightgrey;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a.fancylink:active {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* added for the demo to be visible: */

body {
  background: #333;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<a class="fancylink" href="#">This is a fancy link</a>
```